# How to hide Sublime inline errors (phantoms) with Escape

Tags: sublimetext3

So the problem is to assign this to Escape without overriding any other functionality. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
{
  "keys": ["escape"],
  "command": "exec",
  "args": {"hide_phantoms_only" : true },
  "context": [ { "key": "phantom_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }],
},
```

I haven't found any documentation on which context keys exist, so `phantom_visible` was just a guess.

Comment: good question - unfortunately it seems like there is no context atm to tell when build error phantoms are visible: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/keyboard-binding-to-dismiss-inline-build-errors/21956

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment Sublime Text (at the time of writing, build 3126) does not have a context that you can use in a keybinding to tell when inline build error phantoms are shown. This has been briefly [discussed in the ST forums](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/keyboard-binding-to-dismiss-inline-build-errors/21956) so it is possible that a future build will contain this functionality.

In the meantime, inspired by [this post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/multiple-keybinding-of-escape-key/12815), we could potentially try to create a keybinding that won't conflict with the default <kbd>Esc</kbd> behavior. But it's worth bearing in mind that the default keybindings may change so we will need to watch for it when updating ST, to see whether this is still relevant/correctly covers all scenarios:

```
{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "exec", "args": { "hide_phantoms_only": true },
    "context":
    [
        // inverse of all the "escape" key contexts found in the Default keybindings
        { "key": "num_selections", "operator": "equal", "operand": 1 },
        { "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": false },
        { "key": "has_prev_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": false },
        { "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false },
        { "key": "overlay_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Package Control to install [Chain of Command](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command), which allows me to do more than 1 command for each context.

When I press the [esc] key, now it does three things when the panel is visible:

- Hides the panel
- Hides the red error boxes
- Kills the running program

Here is my key mapping for this:

```
[ 
    { "keys": ["escape"],
        "context": [
            { "key": "panel_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
                   ],
        "command": "chain",
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                ["hide_panel", {"cancel": true}],
                ["exec", {"hide_phantoms_only": true}],
                ["exec", {"kill": true}]
            ]
        }
    }
]
```