# Hide inline errors (phantoms) in Sublime Text 4

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

The following used to work in Sublime Text 3, but gives an error in ST4.

```
{
  "keys": ["f10"],
  "command": "exec",
  "args": {"hide_phantoms_only" : true },
},
```

Error message: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hide_phantoms_only'`.

Similar to my previous question here [How to hide Sublime inline errors (phantoms) with Escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910121/how-to-hide-sublime-inline-errors-phantoms-with-escape), but the solution no longer works in Sublime Text 4.

Comment: I believe I have already answered you on the forum https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-do-i-hide-inline-errors-phantoms-with-a-key-binding/58567/3?u=ultrainstinct05

Comment: @AshwinShenoy can you put that answer here as well? Comments are transitory, and external URLs may rot.

Comment: @MattDMo done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s because in ST4, phantoms are no longer used to show build errors. They have been replaced by something called region annotations.

**Sublime Text 3**: Uses Inline phantoms

[image]

**Sublime Text 4**: Uses the so called **region annotations**, that appears on the far right edge of the view. This was done mainly to reduce reflow of the document (since phantoms can cause text to shift around, which results in a somewhat janky experience).

[image]

> Error message: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hide_phantoms_only'

Coming back to this, since phantoms are no longer used in ST4 to show build errors, any phantom related arguments that the `exec` command used to take is also no longer valid. Hence, the error.

Currently, I don’t think there is a way to have a key binding that will close all the error annotations, though there is an open feature request to make annotations more key board friendly (& closing all annotations is a part of that issue)

https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/3422